# IllegalStateException and NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run the following activity but as soon as I click on submit button , my app crashes with the given exception.

I have already separated the declaration and initialisation.

My Complaint.java file is as follows

```
package com.example.android.complaintbox_ritesltd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;



public class Complaint extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mComplaintsDatabaseRegerence;
    private EditText ct;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mComplaintsDatabaseRegerence=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Complaints");
        ct=findViewById(R.id.comp_box);



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complaint);

    }
    public void submitButton(View view) {
        //TODO: Send Complaint to the database
       ComplaintDetails complaintDetails=new ComplaintDetails(ct.getText().toString());
       mComplaintsDatabaseRegerence.push().setValue(complaintDetails);


        //Clears the input box
        ct.setText("");
    }

}
```

and activity_complaint.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Complaint"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#E3F2FD"

    >



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Write Your Complaint Here!"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:hint="Complaint!"
        android:id="@+id/comp_box"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/white_round_corner_box"
        android:layout_margin="14dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_margin="14dp"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:onClick="submitButton"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The errors are:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.complaintbox_ritesltd, PID: 3227
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.complaintbox_ritesltd.Complaint.submitButton(Complaint.java:42)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When writing a question, please use the preview pane to verify your post is formatted as you expect.  I fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Clearly, `ct=findViewById(R.id.comp_box);` returns `null` so at `ComplaintDetails complaintDetails=new ComplaintDetails(ct.getText().toString());` you get NPE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Complaint extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mComplaintsDatabaseRegerence;
    private EditText ct;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complaint);
        mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mComplaintsDatabaseRegerence=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Complaints");
        ct=findViewById(R.id.comp_box); // It needs to be below your setContentView.
    }
}
```

**Reason** :

Cause **onCreate** needs to know what is your layout you using for Your Class.

then you can assign the your `Edittext` or it leads to crash with `nullpointer` Exception.

Comment: Thank you @Ashish! you really saved my time :)